# Physics Flex library for Mobile Programming

Tags: android, ios, flash, flex4, physics-engine

I'm looking for a physics library that is compatible with Flex 4.

Any recommendations?

Will any physics library be compatible with iPhone and Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Box2d](http://www.sideroller.com/wck/), which has an AS3 interface to the Box2D C++ 2D physics engine.

Jesse Sternberg has an Alchemy based [Box2d Flash Alchemy Port + World Construction Kit (AS3 Physics Engine at GitHub)](https://github.com/jesses/wck).

Comment: .. and still you closed the question! i'm confused here :-/